# how to get SharePoint lookup field value using powershell

Tags: powershell, client-object-model

Can anyone show me how can I get the lookup field value?

I used this line of code but it is throwing an error:

```
#$Lookup = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue($listItem["Business_x0020_Unit"])
```

> new-object : Cannot find type
>   [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue]: make sure the assembly
>   containing this type is loaded.

Below is my code.

```
 $loc = "C:\Scripts\ReadListUsingCSOM\dlls" # Location of DLL's
 $siteUrl = "https://collaborate.com/"

$listName = "Project"

Set-Location $loc

Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll")
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll")

#Write-Host "Please enter password for $($siteUrl):"
#$pwd = Read-Host -AsSecureString
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
# Remove or replace line below to change authentication method
#$ctx.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($loginname, $pwd)

$web = $ctx.Web 
$ctx.Load($web) 
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()


$list = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName)
$caml = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$caml.ViewXML = "<View />"

$listItems = $list.GetItems($caml)
$ctx.Load($listItems);
$ctx.ExecuteQuery();

Write-Host " Current web title is '$($web.Title)', $($web.Url)"
Write-Host $listItems.Count
foreach ($listItem in $listItems) 
{ 
    #We have all the list item data. For example, Title. 
$Lookup = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue($listItem["Business_x0020_Unit"])
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue]$listItem["Business_x0020_Unit"]; 
    Write-Host $listItem.ID $listItem["Project_x0020_Full_x0020_Number"] 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using CSOM in your example but the SSOM `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue` type is specified for a Lookup Field.

The line:

```
$Lookup = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue($listItem["Business_x0020_Unit"])
```

have to be replaced with this one:

```
$businessUnit = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue]$listItem["Business_x0020_Unit"]
```

P.S.

How to get the type of a Client Object:

```
$type = $item["Business_x0020_Unit"].GetType()
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: 

Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Scripts\ReadListUsingCSOM\ReadList2.ps1:48 char:1
+ $businessUnit = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue]$item["Business_x0 ...

Comment: There is a typo, this error occurs since $item variable is not initialized. Please replace $item with $listItem

Answer (score 0):

The class you are trying to use is not a client class (not originating from Microsoft.SharePoint.Client).

What you are looking for is [`Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fieldlookupvalue.Aspx)

Comment: Yes, I changed it but it is not working. Can you give a full example?